# How to load CSS in Vaadin project

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7, vaadin8

Is there a setting that enables CSS in a Vaadin Project? I find that sometimes the changes I make in the .csss file load and sometimes they don't without any obvious reason. I tried clearing the cookies in my browser, compiling the theme, setting productionMode to both "false and "true", and nothing makes any difference.

Comment: Cleaning tomcat work directory is not helping either

Comment: How is you application deployed? Make sure that the css file is generated and deployed, if this is, then a F5 in the browser can help

Comment: It's definitely not a matter of pressing a button.

Comment: How is you application deployed? Make sure that the css file is generated and deployed to your servlet engine. Is the new css file there or not?

Comment: You can manually recompile the theme, or delete the generated CSS. When NOT in production mode, the `SCSS` is compiled on the fly if the `CSS` does not exist, so it's probably a matter of "_caching_".

Comment: I did manually recompile the theme and also cleared the cache, but changes are still not loading. I'm not in production mode, and my development environment is Eclipse with Tomcat. I don't know how to check if the css file loads or not. It's definitely there in the project structure and some entries are loaded, but the more recent ones aren't. Seems totally random

Comment: What browser are you using? In Chrome Dev Tools, there's an option to not cache when you've got it open. I find that normally works best for me.

Comment: For testing, you can add a CSS style class and check in browser if it's there. For instance, in Firefox you can show the full CSS file via inspection.